# Page is refreshing on button click while I'm stoping it using JQuery (event.preventDefault method) - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have created a table element and appended it to a div element using jquery.

My code is like:

```
var element="&lt;table id='tbl'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;input type='text' id='txt'/&gt;&lt;/td&gt;

&lt;td&gt;&lt;input type='button' id='close' value='Remove'/&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;";

$('#div1').append(element);
```

And on the button click event of close button I've write the code :

```
$('#close').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#tbl').remove();
});
```

but as I press the remove button page is being refreshing.

Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the event, possibly at the time when the element is not in the DOM. You should use following code for dynamically inserted elements:

```
$('#close').on("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $('#tbl').remove(); });
```